# Do these stacks need to be merged?

Tags: c#, requirements

In a proficiency assessment as part of Exam 98-361, Software Development Fundamentals, this question pops up:

> **Scenario 3-3: Using Stacks**
>
> You are writing a program that uses two stacks. The data in each stack is already in descending order. You need to process the contents of both stacks in such a way that the output is printed on the screen ascending order. How would you write such a program?

Now, I have this scenario already coded. My solution is to iterate over two separate stacks, merge them into a List by popping their items off until the stack is empty, and sort the list into the correct order.

However, it strikes me that the question is a bit vague on whether or not I should be merging the stacks. It's *kind* of implied, but it *kind* of isn't.

***If you were reading this question, how would you interpret it?***

Note that I'm not actually taking this exam, just prepping for it. It's more of a requirements *interpretation* issue, at this point, in my mind.

Comment: I think you're correct. Seems to me there'd be no need to specify *two* stacks unless they were supposed to be merged.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: That's kind of what I thought. The specificity of "two stacks" seemed to imply that they wanted them merged. Any chance you can put this into an answer, so you get credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're correct. That was my initial interpretation (although I agree it seems a bit vague). And on further thought, it seems to me there'd be no need to specify two stacks unless they were supposed to be merged.

Answer (score 3):

My point of view:

```
DECLARE NEW_LIST;
INT COUNT = STACK_A.COUNT() + STACK_B.COUNT()

FOR I=0 TO COUNT-1
    IF STACK_A.PEEK() > STACK_B.PEEK()
       NEW_LIST.ADD(STACK_A.POP())
    ELSE
       NEW_LIST.ADD(STACK_B.POP());
```

Now you have `NEW_LIST` which is sorted - you just need to decide on the printing order 
(reverse for ascending order)

Assuming `m, n` are the initial sizes of the two stacks,

Merging both stacks and then sorting a list will cost you more -

`O((n+m)log(n+m))` for a **quicksort**, which is obviously slower than

`O(m+n)`  - for the solution above

Comment: Why not just use the managed stack for this? I think that is more what they are after. But the solution above should probably be ok.

Comment: That's my way of interpreting the question, what's the -1 for? that's the answer *I* would give to this question, and the OP can surely find this post useful. OP mentioned he got this one figured by merging and sorting; It's true that knowing how to actually code something is important in job interviews, but some employers *do* look for an optimized solution rather than a simple, slow one. Software Engineers surely need to take this one in mind!

Comment: I do find the answer useful, as it makes me think of performance. However, this particular question isn't about performance. It's specifically designed to test my knowledge of working with stacks. I won't complicate it by delving into anything else. :)

Comment: @Shai Fair enough, I can remove my downvote if you edit your answer (any trivial edit should do it)

Comment: @MikeHofer well atleast you got *another* prespective to the question which will help you deal with more complicated tasks in the future

Comment: @Shai, I gave you the upvote for *making* me think about performance. Your sample is an eye-opener, but it didn't directly address my question. Still, it's a decent code sample.

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds like a set-up for a merge-sort; to get the contents of both in a combined, sorted (but reversed) order, you repeatedly peek the top of each stack to see which value is lower (id est, earlier in a descending order sort), pop the value off that stack and push it to a third stack. Repeat until both source stacks are empty, and because your third stack is FILO the items you added in descending order will pop off in ascending order.